# Which real analytic functions of two variables locally are magnitudes of complex-analytic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume we have a real-analytic function $f(x, y)>0$ in some neighborhood of 0. When does there exist a complex-analytic function $w(z)$ such that $|w(z)|=f(x,y)$ for $z=x+iy$.

One necessary condition is that $\Delta\ln f=0$. Is there anything else?

Comment: Why aren't you done then? If $\ln f$ is harmonic, then you can add its harmonic conjugate, exponentiate et voila

Comment: This is true if your neighborhood is simply connected.

Comment: @Alexandre, Yes, I meant small $\epsilon$-neighborhood

Comment: Voting to close as it is answered in the comments. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formally complete the question: the answer is by Anthony Quas in the comment below.